# ng update automatically updating packages to version 12.0.0-next.0

Tags: angular, npm

I've been updating some projects to angular 11 from angular 10 and have been running into a problem when running ng update. For some reason within the last couple days ng update has started updating some of my packages to 12.0.0-next.0. I know this is a recent pre-release and from reading the documentation it seems like ng update should only install pre-releases when --next=true.

I have tried reinstalling the angular cli along with a number of commands to try and force the version like: `ng update @angular/cdk@11.2.0 @angular/cli@11.2.0 @angular/core@11.2.0 @angular/material@11.2.0 --force --next=false` but it still installs that pre-release version 12.

Is there a reason it is forcing me to 12.0.0-next.0? Is there a work around for this?

Comment: Their maintainers could have published something incorrectly. You can always set a specific version in your package.json file and wait to see if it gets fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same for me. Try just this first:

```
ng update @angular/cli@^11 @angular/core@^11
```

and after that what else should be updated:

```
ng update @angular/cdk@^11 @angular/material@^11
```

Let me know how everything works out for you!